# ngSwitch no funciona de forma correcta

Tags: javascript, angular

Hola tengo el siguiente codigo no se que pasa pero no funciona

```
<div [ngSwitch]="nextHour[16]">
        <div *ngSwitchCase="Nublado - Lluvias con probabilidad de tormenta">
          <img class="card-img-top img-thumbnail" src="assets/img/tormenta.png" alt="Card image cap">
        </div>
        <div *ngSwitchCase="Nublado">
          <img class="card-img-top img-thumbnail" src="assets/img/nublado.png" alt="Card image cap">
        </div>
        <div *ngSwitchCase="Nublado - Llovizna">
          <img class="card-img-top img-thumbnail" src="assets/img/raining.png" alt="Card image cap">
        </div>
        <div *ngSwitchCase="Nublado - Lluvia">
          <img class="card-img-top img-thumbnail" src="assets/img/raining.png" alt="Card image cap">
        </div>
        <div *ngSwitchCase="Parcialmente nublado">
          <img class="card-img-top img-thumbnail" src="assets/img/parcialmente.png" alt="Card image cap">
        </div>
        <div *ngSwitchCase="Despejado">
          <img class="card-img-top img-thumbnail" src="assets/img/sun.png" alt="Card image cap">
        </div>
        <div *ngSwitchCase="Parcialmente nublado - Lluvia">
          <img class="card-img-top img-thumbnail" src="assets/img/raining.png" alt="Card image cap">
        </div>
        <div *ngSwitchCase="Parcialmente nublado - Llovizna">
          <img class="card-img-top img-thumbnail" src="assets/img/raining.png" alt="Card image cap">
        </div>
        <div *ngSwitchCase="Nublado - Lluvias y tormentas fuertes">
          <img class="card-img-top img-thumbnail" src="assets/img/tormenta.png" alt="Card image cap">
        </div>
        <div *ngSwitchCase="Parcialmente nublado - Lluvias con probabilidad de Tormentas">
          <img class="card-img-top img-thumbnail" src="assets/img/tormenta.png" alt="Card image cap">
        </div>
        <div *ngSwitchDefault>

        </div>
      </div>
```

obtengo el siguiente error:

```
Uncaught Error: Template parse errors:
Can't bind to 'ngSwitchCaseCon' since it isn't a known property of 'div'. ("ard m-5" style="width: 30rem;" *ngIf="!loading">
      <div [ngSwitch]="nextHour[16]">
        <div [ERROR ->]*ngSwitchCase="Nublado - Lluvias con probabilidad de tormenta">
          <img class="card-img-top im"): ng:///AppModule/TownComponent.html@19:13
Can't bind to 'ngSwitchCaseDe' since it isn't a known property of 'div'. ("ard m-5" style="width: 30rem;" *ngIf="!loading">
      <div [ngSwitch]="nextHour[16]">
        <div [ERROR ->]*ngSwitchCase="Nublado - Lluvias con probabilidad de tormenta">
          <img class="card-img-top im"): ng:///AppModule/TownComponent.html@19:13
Property binding ngSwitchCaseCon not used by any directive on an embedded template. Make sure that the property name is spelled correctly and all directives are listed in the "@NgModule.declarations". ("ss="card m-5" style="width: 30rem;" *ngIf="!loading">
      <div [ngSwitch]="nextHour[16]">
        [ERROR ->]<div *ngSwitchCase="Nublado - Lluvias con probabilidad de tormenta">
          <img class="card-img-t"): ng:///AppModule/TownComponent.html@19:8
Property binding ngSwitchCaseDe not used by any directive on an embedded template. Make sure that the property name is spelled correctly and all directives are listed in the "@NgModule.declarations". ("ss="card m-5" style="width: 30rem;" *ngIf="!loading">
      <div [ngSwitch]="nextHour[16]">
        [ERROR ->]<div *ngSwitchCase="Nublado - Lluvias con probabilidad de tormenta">
          <img class="card-img-t"): ng:///AppModule/TownComponent.html@19:8
Can't bind to 'ngSwitchCaseY' since it isn't a known property of 'div'. ("g-top img-thumbnail" src="assets/img/raining.png" alt="Card image cap">
        </div>
        <div [ERROR ->]*ngSwitchCase="Nublado - Lluvias y tormentas fuertes">
          <img class="card-img-top img-thumbna"): ng:///AppModule/TownComponent.html@43:13
Property binding ngSwitchCaseY not used by any directive on an embedded template. Make sure that the property name is spelled correctly and all directives are listed in the "@NgModule.declarations". ("rd-img-top img-thumbnail" src="assets/img/raining.png" alt="Card image cap">
        </div>
        [ERROR ->]<div *ngSwitchCase="Nublado - Lluvias y tormentas fuertes">
          <img class="card-img-top img-th"): ng:///AppModule/TownComponent.html@43:8
Can't bind to 'ngSwitchCaseNublado-Lluvias' since it isn't a known property of 'div'. ("-top img-thumbnail" src="assets/img/tormenta.png" alt="Card image cap">
        </div>
        <div [ERROR ->]*ngSwitchCase="Parcialmente nublado - Lluvias con probabilidad de Tormentas">
          <img class="c"): ng:///AppModule/TownComponent.html@46:13
Can't bind to 'ngSwitchCaseProbabilidad' since it isn't a known property of 'div'. ("-top img-thumbnail" src="assets/img/tormenta.png" alt="Card image cap">
        </div>
        <div [ERROR ->]*ngSwitchCase="Parcialmente nublado - Lluvias con probabilidad de Tormentas">
          <img class="c"): ng:///AppModule/TownComponent.html@46:13
Property binding ngSwitchCaseNublado-Lluvias not used by any directive on an embedded template. Make sure that the property name is spelled correctly and all directives are listed in the "@NgModule.declarations". ("d-img-top img-thumbnail" src="assets/img/tormenta.png" alt="Card image cap">
        </div>
        [ERROR ->]<div *ngSwitchCase="Parcialmente nublado - Lluvias con probabilidad de Tormentas">
          <img cla"): ng:///AppModule/TownComponent.html@46:8
Property binding ngSwitchCaseProbabilidad not used by any directive on an embedded template. Make sure that the property name is spelled correctly and all directives are listed in the "@NgModule.declarations". ("d-img-top img-thumbnail" src="assets/img/tormenta.png" alt="Card image cap">
        </div>
        [ERROR ->]<div *ngSwitchCase="Parcialmente nublado -
```

es un simple Switch hecho en angular 7

Comment: Hola, ya logre solucionarlo, era cuestion de agregar la ' en la compraracion de cada item  *ngSwitchCase="'Nublado - Lluvias y tormentas fuertes'"